# Countable sets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $C$ be a certain set of pairwise co-prime balanced rectangles in a plane. need to prove that C is a Countable set. The meaning of balanced rectangles is a set of the next form: $$B=<x,y>\in \mathbb{R}^2:a\le x\le b, c\le y\le d$$ for $a,b,c,d$ such that: $a<b \ and \ c<d$.

- I need to use the density of $\mathbb{Q} \ in \ (\mathbb{R},\le)$.

---

I don't know how to even start proving. Therefore, I will be happy to get some help.

Comment: If you don't require that $a, b, c ,d \in \mathbb Q$, this can't be true as the sets $[0, a] \times [0, a]$ are in $B$ for any real number $a>0$, so we have found an uncountably infinite subset of $B$.

Comment: @Ramanujan and if it is required?

Comment: what does "pairwise co-prime" mean for rectangles?

Comment: @shortmanikos meaning that the intersection between each couple is empty.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as a duplicate; formally, of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345791/countable-or-uncountable-family-of-disjoint-triangles), but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974322) is more directly relevant (has no upvoted answer), and links to some other questions that should be helpful.